# Phpmyadmin #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have been trying to put my localhost fivem rp server to zaphosting with phpmyadmin from mysql when i first tried i came across #1101 - BLOB/TEXT column 'house' can't have a default value error but i got in contact with someone at zaphosting and i fixed it but then after i dont that i keep getting this error now:

Static analysis:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}'" at position 1268)
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "11" at position 1407)
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "DEFAULT" at position 1411)
> SQL query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    identifier varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL, 
    license varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    money int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    skin longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    job varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT 'unemployed', 
    job_grade int(11) DEFAULT 0, 
    loadout longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    position varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '{"x":195.55,"y":-933.36,"z":29.90,"heading":100.0}', 
    bank int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    permission_level int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    group varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    is_dead tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0, 
    firstname varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    lastname varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    dateofbirth varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    sex varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    height varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    status longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    phone_number varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    jail int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    house longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL '{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}', bought_furniture 
    longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}', 
    last_house int(11) DEFAULT 0, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}',
> bought_furniture longtext COLL' at line 24

then i told the person at zaphosting about this error and i got a responds saying sadly there is no fix unless i was good with mysql so does anyone know a fix ?

This is the script thats giving me that error::

```
-- Dumping structure for table essentialmode.users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identifier` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `license` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `money` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  `skin` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT 'unemployed',
  `job_grade` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `loadout` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '{"x":195.55,"y":-933.36,"z":29.90,"heading":100.0}',
  `bank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_dead` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `firstname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  `dateofbirth` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  `sex` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  `height` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  `status` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `jail` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `house` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}',
  `bought_furniture` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
  `last_house` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` does not work with SQLServer so I have removed the irrelevant tag. PLease dont spam tags, they are used to gather the correct audience to your question, if you use irrelevant tags it does not help

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to format your question so it is readable, why should we stop long enough to read it?

Comment: What version of mariaDB are you using and what version of `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: That code works with `10.4.10-MariaDB` using `phpMyAdmin 5.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is missing `DEFAULT` on the line with ‘house’:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    identifier varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL, 
    license varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    money int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    skin longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    job varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT 'unemployed', 
    job_grade int(11) DEFAULT 0, 
    loadout longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    position varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '{"x":195.55,"y":-933.36,"z":29.90,"heading":100.0}', 
    bank int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    permission_level int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    group varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    is_dead tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0, 
    firstname varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    lastname varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    dateofbirth varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    sex varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    height varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '', 
    status longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    phone_number varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    jail int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    house longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}', bought_furniture 
    longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}', 
    last_house int(11) DEFAULT 0, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```